# Empty rows after binding a DataTable to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I have a `DataTable` with ending spaces in one of the column names.

Lets say, we have table in database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Text_with_pk](
    [char_ 10    ] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [nchar_10] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [varchar_max] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Text_with_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Column `[char_ 10    ]` has ending spaces in it's name.

Than I read content of this table into `DataTable` and bind it to `DataGrid`.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" 
                      x:Name="PreviewDataGrid"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                      SelectedValuePath="SelectedCells"
                      SelectedCellsChanged="PreviewDataGrid_OnSelectedCellsChanged"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
                      AutoGeneratingColumn="PreviewDataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn">
        </DataGrid>
```

I tried to add column binding to escape special symbols / white spaces in column name.

```
private void PreviewDataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        var column = (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn);

        if (column != null)
        {
            column.Binding = new Binding($"[{e.PropertyName}]");
            column.Header = e.PropertyName;
            column.Binding.TargetNullValue = "NULL";
        }
    }
```

But it does not work and I keep getting this error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'Item[]' value (type 'Object') from '' (type 'DataRowView'). BindingExpression:Path=[QOF754    ]; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=19681030); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') TargetInvocationException:'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: QOF754 is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table [dbo].[Test].
   at System.Data.DataRowView.get_Item(String property)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.GetValue(Object item, Int32 level)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.RawValue(Int32 k)'
```

I dont know table structure, column names in advance. So I need to handle all scenarios.

Here `[QOF754    ]` is actual column name.

I tried to escape it in `Converter`:

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding Data, Converter={StaticResource DataGridConverter}}"


 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return null;

            var dataTable = value as DataTable;
            if (dataTable != null)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
                {

                    column.ColumnName = column.ColumnName.Trim();
                }
            }

            return value;
        }
```

But then column name is different (trimmed) and this is not working for me.

How can I bind such columns-with-trailing-space to my DataGrid and make it working?